# Chave estrangeira conjunta entre campo index e uma possível string

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou criando uma aplicação onde eu pensei em uma possibilidade de inserir todos os endereços existentes no sistema em uma única tabela, tanto para usuários, clientes, fornecedores etc. a estrutura da minha tabela então ficaria assim:

```
__id => CHAVE_PRIMÁRIA
__status
* idReferencia => CHAVE_EXTRANGEIRA_CONJUNTA (REF. GENÉRICA COM BASE NO txTabela)
* txTabela  => CHAVE_EXTRANGEIRA_CONJUNTA (STRING: 'CLIENTE','FORNECEDOR',etc)
txGenero
nmCep
txLogradouro
txComplemento
txBairro
txLocalidade
txUf
txIbge
```

Existe alguma forma de que eu consiga montar esta chave extrangeira utilizando uma string existente no campo `txTabela`? ou eu terei que manter estes endereços em inúmeras tabelas diferentes e aumentando significativamente o tamanho do meu banco de dados sem necessidade? (obs, isso também ocorreria com contatos, documentos e outros tipos de valores genéricos)

Eu tenho certeza que se eu não utilizar Chaves estrangeiras eu vou conseguir construir a estrutura do meu sistema por completo, mas com as chaves o carregamento de dados melhora..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu lugar, eu faria uma associação N para N com uma `CHECK CONSTRAINT` pra verificar se só uma das FKs está preenchida:

```
CREATE TABLE ENDERECO 
(
    ENDERECO_ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    STATUS VARCHAR(10),
    GENERO VARCHAR(10),
    CEP VARCHAR(8)
    LOGRADOURO VARCHAR(500),
    COMPLEMENTO VARCHAR(500),
    BAIRRO VARCHAR(100),
    LOCALIDADE VARCHAR(255),
    UF CHAR(2),
    IBGE NUMERIC(10)
);

CREATE TABLE ENDERECO_RELACOES (
    ENDERECO_RELACAO_ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    ENDERECO_ID INT,
    CLIENTE_ID INT NULL,
    FORNECEDOR_ID INT NULL
    OUTRA_TABELA_ID INT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT ENDERECO_REL_ENDERECO_FK FOREIGN KEY (ENDERECO_ID) REFERENCES ENDERECO (ENDERECO_ID),
    CONSTRAINT ENDERECO_REL_FORNECEDOR_FK FOREIGN KEY (FORNECEDOR_ID) REFERENCES FORNECEDOR (FORNECEDOR_ID),
    CONSTRAINT ENDERECO_REL_CLIENTE_FK FOREIGN KEY (CLIENTE) REFERENCES CLIENTE (CLIENTE_ID),
    CONSTRAINT ENDERECO_REL_OUTRA_TABELA_FK FOREIGN KEY (OUTRA_TABELA_ID) REFERENCES OUTRA_TABELA (OUTRA_TABELA_ID)
);

ALTER TABLE ENDERECO_RELACOES 
ADD CONSTRAINT CheckFKs
CHECK (
(CASE WHEN CLIENTE_ID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    + CASE WHEN FORNECEDOR_ID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    + CASE WHEN OUTRA_TABELA_ID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    = 1
);
```

Comment: sim, mas fazendo assim eu aumento 1 relacionamento. e como endereços não são registros tão flexíveis não tem problema eu ter um vínculo baseado em dados dentro da tabela... minha intenção é reduzir o número de tabelas repetitivas com base em colunas associativas de dentro do programa

Comment: Qualquer coisa diferente disso você está criando uma fragilidade referencial dentro do seu banco. Alguns Frameworks usam *discriminators*, que são colunas string que indicam de qual tabela a chave veio, mas são **associações fracas**, não conferidas pelo banco de dados. Eu posso dar outra resposta bem mais complexa, com conferência por triggers, mas acho um capricho perto da resposta fornecida.

Comment: sim concordo, que poderia gerar uma fragilidade no banco de dados, mas para o tipo de dado a ser utilizado, e a forma de administração do que estou querendo construir, creio que seja uma opção "criativa". no caso das informações que serão inseridas elas já são associações fracas portanto não tem problema ;D